# Question about java mail API functionality

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am working on Java Mail API and i need to develop a general mail module which should be capable of sending various types of mail..
like

- OrderConfirmation
- SomePromotion related Mails
- Some other general alerts mail
- all with or without attachments and yes with lots of contents like images flash etc..

we also need to develop a functionality so that can send newsletters/alerts to bulk users
though my module is working fine,but my query is what is the best way to send and handle such bulk mail system since depending upon third party solutions never gives so much flexibility.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, so what is your question? Yes, you can do all those things with the JavaMail API.

Comment: @Jesper question is any better way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'd suggest you the wrapper over the JMail from Jakarta: http://commons.apache.org/email/
2. To create flexible system use [velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) for text generation.

Comment: velocity is the one of the option for text generation and i was not aware about the Jakarta email need to look in to that.Thanks for the info..:)

Answer (score 0):

@umesh as @AlexR suggested ,it is good to use Commons Email Library and Some templating system to maintain different mail templates.

Along with that, to ensure smooth delivery of bulk mailing process few thing are to be handled too,I suggest to maintain a failover which maintains history of all mails sent so that, if in case if server or network breaks down mails can be resent from the point of failover.

Comment: thanks for the added tips that's really helpful,but i was looking at Common Email and not saw anything they are providing out of box only the handling has been improved but there was nothing which made me to think that we should go for it.any idea what best it is offering

Comment: @umesh one of the best things in commons mail library is , user can send html emails i.e, user can modify html content using some template library or regular string replacement techniques for adding dynamic content

Comment: OK thats true and for that i was planning to use velocity which will do the same..my idea was that if i will go to common mail means i have to ait for them to add new funcionality or do enhancment on my own so this making my mind to work directly with underlying API,though the work will be much larger since it needs to be done but flexibility to modify enhance is much fine grained